# Calculate the percentile of products in ms-access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 fields in a table, namely category, product, avg.sales. How do I calculate the percentile of each product under its respective category? Currently, I make different tables for each category and then calculate the percentile, but is it possible to do it in just one table?

Here is the code that I used. "**MobilesCount**" is another query which stores the total number of products in mobile category. I hope this helps

```
SELECT 
    o.CategoryID, 
    o.product, 
    o.brand, 
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(i.[Avg Sales]) 
     FROM 
        [ProductItemsSold] i 
     WHERE 
        i.[Avg Sales] <= o.[Avg Sales] 
        AND 
        CategoryID = 28 
        AND 
        [Avg Sales]>0
    )/(SELECT [Total Products] From MobilesCount) AS [Sales percentile]
FROM 
    [ProductItemsSold(Weekly)] AS o
WHERE 
    o.CategoryID = 28 
    AND 
    o.[Avg Sales]>0
ORDER BY 
    o.product;
```

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Can you provide sample data/desired outcome?

Comment: I can't add images, there is some problem with this account